# Regex Error: Nothing to Repeat

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regular expressions in JavaScript, and I cannot get a regex to work. The error is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: `/(.*+x.*+)\=(.++)/`: Nothing to repeat

I know there are many questions like this other than this, but I cannot get this to work based on other people's answers and suggestions.

The regex is:

```
/(.*+x.*+)\=(.++)/
```

and it is used to match simple equations with the variable `x` on one side.

Some examples of the expressions it's supposed to match are (I'm writing a simple program to solve for the variable `x`):

- `240x=70`
- `x+70=23`
- `520/x=2`
- `13989203890189038902890389018930.23123213281903890128390x+23123/2=3`
- etc.

I'm trying out possessive quantifiers (`*+`) because before, the expressions were greedy and crashed my browser, but now this error that I haven't encountered has come up.

I'm sure it doesn't have to do with escaping, which was the problem for many other people.

Comment: `.*+` doesn't make sense... What do you want that to represent? You probably just want `.*` (which means one or more of any character).

Comment: @jahroy You do know that I'm doing that on purpose, right? As a possessive quantifier (`*+`) instead of a greedy quantifier (`*`)? Or am I using this wrong?

Comment: After re-reading, it appears that you're doing it on purpose, but aren't quite doing it correctly ;-)

Comment: @jahroy What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mean like this? [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/fM9dZ3)

Comment: Ok... I just googled _possesive quantifiers_ and the first thing I notice is that JavaScript does **NOT** support them.

Comment: @jahroy That could explain it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can emulate a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) with javascript (since you can emulate an [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) that is the same thing):

```
a++ => (?>a+) => (?=(a+))\1
```

The trick use the fact that the content of a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=...)` becomes atomic once the closing parenthesis reached by the regex engine. If you put a capturing group inside (with what you want to be atomic or possessive), you only need to add a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\1` to the capture group after.

About your pattern:

`.*+x` is an always false assertion (like `.*+=`): since `.*` is greedy, it will match all possible characters, if you make it possessive `.*+`, the regex engine can not backtrack to match the "x" after.

What you can do:

Instead of using the vague `.*`, I suggest to describe more explicitly what can contain each capture group. I don't think you need possessive quantifiers for this task.

Trying to split the string on operator can be a good idea too, and avoids to build too complex patterns.

Comment: @Jon: try to match `aaaaaaab` with `a+ab` and `(?=(a+))\1ab`. The first pattern allows the regex engine to backtrack, but the second not.

Comment: What does the `?=` do? I thought atomic groups only started with `?>`. And what is the `\1` after the regex? Sorry I'm new to regular expressions.

Comment: I tried using the following regex: `/(?=(.*x.*))\=(?=(.+))/i` but it's not matching anything.

Comment: @Jon: To well understand the pattern, you need to be familiar with several regex notions, in particular with the backtracking mechanism (it's the key of all). I added several links in my answer for each quoted notion. But I suggest to read first (on the same site) pages about lazy and greedy quantifiers, before possessive quantifiers and atomic groups (don't put the cart before the horse). However, as I wrote it at the end of my post, possessive quantifiers are not needed for the task you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript regular expressions don't support possessive quantifiers. You should try with the reluctant (non-greedy) ones: `*?` or `+?`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will seperate the left hand side and the right hand side:

```
(.*x.*)=(.+)
```

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dH4kQ0)