# Free text parsing using long regex formula leading to error: multiple repeat in python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, parsing, spyder

I need to parse specific strings from a free text field in an .xlsx file. I am using Python 2.7 in Spyder.

I escaped the '.' in the regex formulas but I am still getting the same error.

To do that, I used pandas to convert the .xslx file into a pandas dataframe:

```
data = "complaints_data.xlsx"
read_data = pd.read_excel(data)
read_data.dropna(inplace = False)
df = pd.DataFrame(read_data)
df['FMEA Assessment'] = df['FMEA Assessment'].replace({',':''}, regex=True)
```

Then, I used the extract function of pandas to extract my string fields FMEA, Rev and Line using regex patterns.

```
fmea_pattern = r'(FMEA\s*\d*\d*\d*\d*\d*|fmea\s*\d*\d*\d*\d*\d*|DOC\s*\-*[0]\d*\d*\d*\d*\d*|doc\s*\-*[0]\d*\d*\d*\d*\d*)'
df[['FMEA']] = df['FMEA Assessment'].str.extract(fmea_pattern, expand=True)
    
rev_pattern = r'(Rev\.*\s+\D{1,2}+|rev\.*\s+\D{1,2}|REV\.*\s+\D{1,2}|rev\.*\s+\D{1,2})'
df[['REV']] = df['FMEA Assessment'].str.extract(rev_pattern, expand=True)
    


line_pattern = r'(line item\.*\s*\:*\d{1,3}\d*\.*\D*\.*\d+\d*?\.|Line\.*\s*\:*\d{1,3}\d*\.*\D*\.*\d+\d*?\.|lines\.*\s*\:*\d{1,3}\d*\.*\D*\.*\d+\d*?\.|Lines\.*\s*\:*\d{1,3}\d*\.*\D*\.*\d+\d*?\.|Line item\.*\s*\:*\d{1,3}\d*\.*\D*\.*\d+\d*?\.|LINES\.*\s*\:*\d{1,3}\d*\.*\D*\.*\d+\d*?\.|LINE\.*\s*\:*\d{1,3}\d*\.*\D*\.*\d+\d*?\.)'
df[['LINE']] = df['FMEA Assessment'].str.extract(line_pattern, expand=True)
```

The string fields I need to parse can be inputted in various ways and I accounted for each way in the regex formulas and for each variation of a word; for example, I accounted for line, Line, LINE, lines, Lines, etc. I have tested the regex formulas individually and separately and they are working properly. However, when I combine all of them in the code above, I get the following error message:

[image: Error Message Screenshot]

Also, is there another way to account for variations of the same word at the same time(lower case, upper case and title case)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Python 3.11 and newer***

[`re` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) now supports possessive qunatifiers similarly to PCRE, and this issue no longer exists.

> **`*+, ++, ?+`**
> Like the `*`, `+`, and `?` quantifiers, those where `+` is appended also match as many times as possible. However, unlike the true greedy quantifiers, these do not allow back-tracking when the expression following it fails to match. These are known as possessive quantifiers. For example, `a*a` will match `aaaa` because the `a*` will match all 4 `a`s, but, when the final `a` is encountered, the expression is backtracked so that in the end the `a*` ends up matching 3 `a`s total, and the fourth `a` is matched by the final `a`. However, when `a*+a` is used to match `aaaa`, the `a*+` will match all 4 `a`, but when the final `a` fails to find any more characters to match, the expression cannot be backtracked and will thus fail to match. `x*+`, `x++` and `x?+` are equivalent to `(?>x*)`, `(?>x+)` and `(?>x?)` correspondingly.
>
> *New in version 3.11.*

and

> **`{m,n}+`**
> Causes the resulting RE to match from *m* to *n* repetitions of the preceding RE, attempting to match as many repetitions as possible *without* establishing any backtracking points. This is the possessive version of the quantifier above. For example, on the 6-character string `'aaaaaa'`, `a{3,5}+aa` attempt to match 5 `'a'` characters, then, requiring 2 more `'a'`s, will need more characters than available and thus fail, while `a{3,5}aa` will match with `a{3,5}` capturing 5, then 4 `'a'`s by backtracking and then the final 2 `'a'`s are matched by the final `aa` in the pattern. `x{m,n}+` is equivalent to `(?>x{m,n})`.
>
> *New in version 3.11.*

***Python versions below 3.11***

The main error in this case is due to the fact you are using a possessive quantifier instead of a regular, non-possessive quantifier.

It is a common mistake when users test their patterns in the online PCRE regex testers. You need to make sure you ALWAYS test your regexps in the environment (or with a regex engine option) that is compatible with your target environment.

**Python `re` does not support possessive quantifiers**:

```
{5}+
{5,}+
{5,10}+
++
?+
*+
```

In this case, **you just need to remove the trailing `+` from `\D{1,2}+`**:

```
rev_pattern = r'(Rev\.*\s+\D{1,2}|rev\.*\s+\D{1,2}|REV\.*\s+\D{1,2}|rev\.*\s+\D{1,2})'
```

It seems you may just use

```
rev_pattern = r'((?:[Rr]ev|REV)\.*\s+\D{1,2})' # Will only match Rev, REV and rev at the start
rev_pattern = r'(?i)(Rev\.*\s+\D{1,2})' # Will match any case variations of Rev
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Px7FOP/1) at Regex101, note the `Python` option selected on the left.

Also, note that it is possible to make the whole pattern case insensitive by adding `(?i)` at the start of the pattern, or by compiling the regex with `re.I` or `re.IGNORECASE` arguments. This will "account for variations of the same word at the same time(lower case, upper case and title case)".

**NOTE**: if you actually are looking to use a possessive quantifier you may [**emulate a possessive quantifier**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175939) with the help of a positive lookahead and a backreference. However, in Python, you would need `re.finditer` to get access to the whole match values.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand my error now. 

Could you please help me match the following string using regex? I am not sure why my regex formula captures the entire sentence.

`p = r'(line\.*\s*\:*\d{1,3}\d*\.*\D*\.*\d+\d*?\.), 
string = "fsfdsfsdfsd Line 43: Seal and retainer assembly not performed pfghfghfg fhfghsis"`

I would like to extract only line 43 but my formula captures the entire string after line 43.


Thank you!

Comment: @brightcitrus I do not understand the rule, the requirements, try just `r'(?i)(line\.*\s*\d+)'`

Comment: The line field could be in multiple formats: line d, line dd, line ddd, line d.A.d, line dA, line d.A. The regex I have captures most of them but then picks up leftover strings.

Comment: @brightcitrus Please use [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Px7FOP/1) to share test cases. I still do not understand what exact format you need to match.  I suggest asking a new question.